# youtube reporting api error 500 internal error

Tags: youtube-api, reporting

after few moonths using youtube reporting api from a C# console app to download reports as content manager, today I am receiving code 500 error (Internal error). Nothing has changed in the relevant code, and everything always went smoothly before. I am receiving the same error in Google API's Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

The YouTube API Reporting service was out of service. I just have to wait for a few hours and everything was working fine again